# Failed to map the path '/WorkArea/' on my development machine

Tags: asp.net, ektron

I have a .net program using Ektron APIs to get folder list and its details. It was working before on my development machine.  Now it doesn't work any more.  I notice, we have upgraded to Ektron 8.xx from 7.xx.

When I ran the same codes but it gave me this error:

```
                  Failed to map the path '/WorkArea/'.
```

I had no idea why. I'm running this test program on visual studio 2010.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the code that generates the error so we have something to start with

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem (Ektron version **8.6.1**) trying to run a 3-Tier minsite on my local machine (for dev), talking to a (staging) Application Tier.

First I followed [the instructions for setting up a Presentation Tier](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v8.61/Reference/Web/3-Tier/3-Tier.htm)

One thing that is *not* mentioned in these instructions is the requirement that your Presentation Tier site's virtual path match that of the `appSettings > ek_sitePath` value in the Application Tier's `web.config`. By default, this value is `/`.

By default, when you open/create a Web Site Project and use the built-in VS server for development, the site's path looks like `http://localhost:wxyz/SiteName`.

So you have 2 options:

1. Change the `web.config` on Application Tier so `appSettings > ek_sitePath` is the same as `/SiteName` (probably not the best option, since any new site development will require changing this again, and it could break production sites)
2. Change the virtual path of your Presentation Tier site to `/`, which is easy to do as outlined in this [ScottGu blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/19/tip-trick-how-to-run-a-root-site-with-the-local-web-server-using-vs-2005-sp1.aspx) (talks about VS 2005, I use 2010 and it was the same process)

I took the latter approach, and everything is working smoothly now!